# Spring - Autowiring a map

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I have a map in my spring xml defined as follows

```
    <!-- Home Screen Backrgound Image Service  -->
<bean id="homeScreenBackgroundImageService" class="com.services.images.impl.HomeScreenBackgroundImageServiceImpl" parent="imageServicesParent">
</bean>


<util:map id="imageServicesMap" value-type="com.services.images.ImageServicesParent">
  <!-- Map between String key and List -->
  <entry key="bean1" value-ref="homeScreenBackgroundImageService" />
```

When I inject this map into a class. My key is bean1
However, when this map is autowired homeScreenBackgroundImageService

I need to use autowiring to access this bean but how can I set it up so I can reference the beans in the map using the key bean1 as opposed homeScreenBackgroundImageService?

Unfortunately for my use case I need to use a map.
I amn using Spring 4.1.4.RELEASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry - found the answer nearly straight away - posting answer for completeness

Instead of autowiring like this

```
   @Autowired
   private ImageServicesParent imageServicesMap;
```

Use @resource instead and it will work

```
   @Resource
   private ImageServicesParent imageServicesMap;
```